# XAMPP/Wordpress is using a different IP address after new modem

Tags: wordpress, xampp, windows-10

So my ip address has changed so I can no longer access my WP Admin from my pc. It's redirecting to a different device/ip on my wifi so, therefore, cannot access it on my PC anymore. Can I edit/reset the Wordpress settings from ftp or PHPMyAdmin? So it points to localhost instead of a different device ip?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with my windows ten (my other Samsung Computer)
So I searched this up.
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-not-working/
This actually contains 3 common solutions to the problems that we both have had and are having.

1. Resolve Apache Port Conflicts (This actually fixed my problem)
2. Include the Listening Port in the Address When Accessing Localhost
3. Change Your MySQL Port (Although I think this is the least helpful one)
   For more explanation, click on the link above.